# Check 2 tables for differences, use programming language or pure SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to check 2 tables (10k plus rows) for inconsistent data.  e.g. both table have a "id" and "price" column and I want to know when id are equal are the price also equal.  I would like to create a output that tells me exactly which id have different/inconsistent prices.

Is this more efficiently done with pure SQL or with a programming language + SQL.  Since I'm new to SQL I don't know how trivial this would be with pure SQL.

Comment: Asking whether something is "better" is off topic, because its down to opinion. I suggest you ask the question "how to do it in SQL" (and have a go because its not difficult), then you can decide which is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `id` is unique on the rows, then a `join` is sufficient:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.price <> t2.price;
```

Note:  Your question only focuses on ids that are in *both* tables.  If you want *all* ids and to know if the value is missing, then you can use `full join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.price = t2.price
where t1.id is null or t2.id is null;
```

Comment: How bout checking on multiple servers say I have to check t1 with t1a,t1b,t1c each on their own server.  Would pure sql also be efficient in this case?

Comment: @bakalolo . . . It depends on the relationship between the servers.  If you use linked servers, the queries are essentially the same.  Actually the tables are not very large, so SQL is probably still feasible.